# Why does JQuery UI Datepicker stop working after I add an unrelated div to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form with two datepicker text boxes (start and end dates) and a submit button (type="button"). The html looks like so:

```
 <div class="subForm">
  <h3>
    Input start/end dates and station ID or lat/lon location to get point surge
    in the desired time frame:
  </h3>

  <br>
  <br>

  <form>
    <span>
      Start Date:
      <br>
      <input id="sdate" type="text">
    </span>

    <span>
      End Date:
      <br>
      <input id="edate" type="text">
    </span>

    <span>
      Station ID:
      <br>
      <select id="stns"></select>
    </span>

    <span>
      <br>
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Get Surge"/>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

I assign datepickers and a click event to the text boxes and button, respectively, using the following jQuery:

```
window.onload = $(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    getArchive();
  });

  // Start/end datepickers
  window.sDateStr = '';
  window.eDateStr = '';
  $('#sdate').datepicker({changeMonth:true,
                          changeYear:true,
                          yearRange:"2002:2020",
                        });
  $('#edate').datepicker({changeMonth:true,
                          changeYear:true,
                          yearRange:"2002:2020",
                        });

  $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index',9000);
});
```

The "subForm" div is located inside of a "wrapper" div, which is in the body. When the user clicks "Get Surge", the form grabs relevant info using Javascript and then appends a div to the wrapper (under the submit form) like so:

```
function display(data) {
  $('#wrapper').html($('#wrapper').html() + '<pre id="pointdata">'+data['ss']+'</pre>');
  $('#pointdata').css({'margin-top':'-6%',
                       'width':'90%',
                       'height':'600px',
                       'margin-left':'5%',
                       'overflow':'scroll',
                       'word-wrap':'break-word',
                       'z-index':'0'});
}
```

At this point, the table containing all the data loads just fine, but then the dates in the text boxes disappear and when I try to re-enter new dates, no calendar pops up.

I've omitted the Javascript that grabs and parses the data because that's not causing the problem. Datepicker only breaks when I call the 'display(data)' function. If I omit that function, the program console.log's the data ok and the datepicker is still useable.

However, the second I try to append a div to '#wrapper', the datepicker breaks. The text box still has the class '.hasdatepicker'. I've tried datepicker('destroy') and removing the '.hasdatepicker' class before reassigning it, but none of those things will fix my problem. I've also made sure to set the z-indexes correctly so that the datepicker has a higher one. I moved the div aside at one point just to make sure there wasn't some odd z-index-not-working problem, but the calendar is actually not displaying. Any suggestions?

Comment: use `$('#wrapper').append(...` instead of `$('#wrapper').html($('#wrapper').html() + ...`

Comment: Yup...that worked. Don't know why I didn't do that. Want to answer the question and get some points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:

What was happening was that you attached the date picker to the dom element using `.datepicker` which attached event listeners to the input field (to trigger itself on the click event).

When using the line

```
$('#wrapper').html($('#wrapper').html() + '<pre id="pointdata">'+data['ss']+'</pre>');
```

You were infact removing the contents of #wrapper and replacing them with itself, doing this will remove all listeners and is the common reason why event delegation is used in jquery (though I don't think your datepicker library supports it)

The simple solution is to append the new contents to the `#wrapper`, same functionality as your `.html()` but it preserves the listeners:

```
$('#wrapper').append('<pre id="pointdata">'+data['ss']+'</pre>');
```